# 7-Zip (7za.dll) .NET wrapper

Tags: .net, 7zip

Is there some code or a library that lets me control the [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) unpacking functionality from C# code?

Comment: For actual 7z files or just ZIP files in general?

Comment: Try what is described in *[C# (.NET) Interface for 7-Zip Archive DLLs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip.aspx)* (article at [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a project on CodePlex, [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/).

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks promising.