# .NET file compression libraries

Tags: .net, compression

I'm looking for a package to use in my project to compress some XML files. I usually use [WinRAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR) to compress files, and I think you can do this using the 7-Zip project and this can be included in a .NET project.

This is a similar Stack Overflow question, *[7-Zip (7za.dll) .NET wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153678/7-zip-7za-dll-net-wrapper)*

and the *The Code Project* example is *[C# (.NET) Interface for 7-Zip Archive DLLs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip.aspx)*.

I particularly want something **simple to use** with a **good compression** ratio. The example provided only extracts files, and I don't particularly have the time to implement and test the compression.

(GZipStream isn't good enough, it compresses my 10 MB file to 9 MB, and WinRAR compresses it to 0.5 MB.)

So, I'm after a library or package (**I don't care if it costs**) which I can include in my project which allows me to easily compress and decompress files that has a good compression ratio and is easy to include and use.

Comment: WinRAR is going to do better than any ZIP based package because RAR is a superior algorithm. You can't use RAR though because the format is protected by legal means (can't remember if it's licensing or patenting that protects it but I believe it is licensing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through a variety of options I have found [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) the best and easiest way to get generate RAR files from my application.

Answer (score 1):

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) is usually my default fallback for .NET compression.

You could also try the [7-Zip SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) (which includes C# bindings). It might provide a better compression ratio than SharpZipLib.

Comment: Note that the 7Zip SDK requires the 7zip DLL to function, IIRC.

Comment: @Billy - You can include it as an item in your project to make sure the DLL gets copied to your project's bin directory.

Comment: Yes -- just pointing that out. Not all of us are in scenarios where it is possible to use a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I think GZipStream only allows you to compress/decompress one single file. If you want to compress a set of files/directory, you could use DotNetZip.

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

I am not sure the compression rate. But DotNetZip products a standard ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

I have to put in a note for [ZipStorer](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/) -- it can also unzip standard ZIP files [I do not know about zip64 or other extensions] :-)

I used it because it is small (~6 KB compiled with just the extraction making it far smaller than DotNetZip which is more than 150 KB) and is more permissive than SharpZipLib. It also has a really small, simple and clean code-base. However, if you do want the features of the others ([gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip), [bzip2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2), encryption, "better" compression, self-extracting, etc.) then you already know where to look.